# Принцип работы vulkan.hpp?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Не понимаю в чем заключается его суть, если он не умеет сам создавать классы, нам все так же требуется вызывать си функции для инициализации классов...

К примеру возьмем класс `vk::Instance`, и посмотрим перегрузки конструкторов:

```
class Instance
{
public:
  VULKAN_HPP_CONSTEXPR Instance()
    : m_instance(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
  {}

  VULKAN_HPP_CONSTEXPR Instance( std::nullptr_t )
    : m_instance(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
  {}

  VULKAN_HPP_TYPESAFE_EXPLICIT Instance( VkInstance instance )
    : m_instance( instance )
  {}
...
// Больше перегрузок нет
```

Т.е. придется вручную делать вызов `vkCreateInstance(...)` и передавать в класс полученный указатель на структуру `VkInstance`? Зачем было так сделано?

Используется стандартная обертка из `Vulkan SDK`.

Comment: Что это за кусок кода? Какая-то обертка для API vulkan? Так используйте какаю-нибудь другую или свою напишите если эта не нравится. В вопросе явно не хватает контекста.

Comment: API Vulcan определяет только С интерфейс. Стандартных биндингов для других языков не определяется. Так что это явно какая-то вендорно-специфическая обертка. Это случаем не Vulkan-Hpp? Так это автогенерируемая обертка.

Comment: Он, но он был включен в `Vulkan SDK`.

Comment: Это который LunarG выпускают?

Comment: Да, именно этот, другого не нашел.